# Where to find infos about functions and opportunities for backup / archive systems

Tags: backup, tape, archive, libraries

we are thinking about building an archive system (>1PB) to store video-files.
Probably this complex system will be assemble by different technologies and sub-systems. But one decisively point will be the type library.

Now, before that project really starts and before we will ask different consultants (and so on), I need to clarify some basics, like:

does modern tape libraries

- has an build-in mechanism to check the quality of an tape and/or change them if the tape is getting old or faulty?
- can provide disk- and tape-storage in one system with an build-in data live-cycle management to move date from disk to tape manually or automaticly?
- can restore only a part of an file, like video-sequence from minute 0:05.20 to 0:08.15?
- has something like an "openAPI", so that different tools can talk to the library? Something like the Restful Web API in the Web 2.0 world to put or get files?

btw: ...i'm not sure, if serverfault is the right StackExchange community.

Thank you

Comment: nice homework question...greater than 1 petabyte of storage hey, and I didn't think I got jealous ;)

Comment: The first two requirements are no big ask to be honest. The 3rd one you might struggle with because it is very hard to identify a place in a video file. Is that time index 10mb into the file or is 100mb into the file? The 4th one I can't say either way